# Getting most common element from list in Python

Tags: python

I was able to use this piece of code to find the most common value if there was only one, however, it wouldn't work if there were multiple. I want it so that if there are multiple, it would just return None.

```
numbers = [5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7]
my_dict = {}
for i in numbers:
    if i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        my_dict[i] = 1

print(max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the key to get the number of occurrences of the highest value.

```
numbers = [5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7]
my_dict = {}
for i in numbers:
    if i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        my_dict[i] = 1

#print(max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get))
mx=max(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
mn=my_dict[mx]
if mn == 1:
  print(mx, ' is the highest')
else:
  print('there are ',mn, ' of ',mx)
```

Output

```
there are  2  of  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a library function to sort the numbers:

```
s = sorted(numbers)
```

Check if the last two numbers are the same (then you have more than one max):

```
one_max = s[-1] if (len(s)==1 or s[-1]!=s[-2]) else None
```

Answer (score 0):

@ada7ke This will print None if there is more than 1 highest number. Otherwise it will print the number

```
numbers = [5, 7, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7]
highest = max(numbers)

indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if x == highest]
frequency = numbers.count(highest)

if frequency > 1:
    print(None)
else:
    print(highest)
```

Comment: `None`, not `"None"`. Also, `numbers.count(highest)` is a better way to find the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, I will do an update on the code.